# FPDF mc table with image

Tags: php, fpdf

I have trouble displaying image (or this time is photo) using mc table FPDF.

This is a little of my script:

```
$pdf=new PDF_MC_Table();
$pdf->SetWidths(array(30,10,30,230));
$pdf->SetAligns(array('L','L','L','C'));
$pdf->Row(array($name, $age, $gender, $photo));
$pdf->Output();
```

`$photo` fill with location of image that I want to display in my PDF table.

The image does not show up at all, instead it shows text of that location

Comment: What is the _"trouble"_ that you're experiencing? Does the image not show up, is it too large, etc.?

Comment: not show up at all, instead its show text of that location

Comment: hmm, do you have the `gd` extension installed? According to the docs [here](http://www.fpdf.org/), that extension is required when working with images...

Comment: I use local drive and use mc table from this http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=3

Comment: The question is about `gd extension`. Is it installed?

Answer (score 1):

I already got the answer

in mc_table.php I add this

```
...
function Row($data)
{
  ...
  for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
  {
    ...
    if(substr($data[$i],-3) == 'jpg' || substr($data[$i],-3) == 'png')
    {
      $ih = $h - 0.5;
      $iw = $w - 0.5;
      $ix = $x + 0.25;
      $iy = $y + 0.25;
      //show image
      $this->MultiCell($w,5,$this->Image ($data[$i],$ix,$iy,$iw),0,$a);
    }else
    {
      //Print the text
      $this->MultiCell($w,5,$data[$i],0,$a);
    }
  ...
  }
}
```

Comment: it works. super clean solution. thank you!